# VS2019-project is unloaded, csproj <UseIISExpress> was changed somehow,

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2019, facebook-c#-sdk

I had a problem and dell premium support ran some kind of upgrade or re-install of windows 10 while keeping my files in tack.

The next day, I was working on my MVC project in VS and it loaded ok and debugging got my application to the login page, which means it had to successfully read the Entity Framework Context with LINQ type stuff, and all of a sudden my project started having these errors about reading Entity Framework Context, but only in one method.

Then **things got worse**, I first tried to close VS and reopen VS. But this time, it said my project had been unloaded. I tried the option to reload the project, but now I was getting errors about **"the operation could not be completed. the system cannot find the path specified"** and errors **having to do with not being able to find the current file highlighted at the top of the VS editor**.

After looking up the unload issues in forums, I saw a suggestion to call up my Mbsa.csproj and change   to false and  to True. Then my project loaded ok - but why did this  change? it was always false in my previous backups.

```
 Then , when trying to run my project with VS Debugging, I started getting connection messages like these:
```

1 - C:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\Mbsa.csproj : error  : The Web Application Project Mbsa is configured to use IIS.  The Web server 'http://localhost:51700/' could not be found.

```
 2 -The connection to 'localhost' failed.
```

Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d).
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:51712

```
 3 - HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
```

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x80070021
Config Error       This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
Config File    \?\D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020\web.config
Requested URL      http://localhost:51700/
Physical Path      D:\MBSSys\Mbsa\Mbsa 2020
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
Config Source:

```
  163:     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  164:     <handlers>
  165:       <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />

   4 - Error message:
```

Server Error in Application "application name"
HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error
HRESULT: 0x80070021
Description of HRESULT
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Cause for HResult code 0x80070021
This problem can occur when the specified portion of the IIS configuration file is locked at a higher configuration level.
Resolution for HResult code 0x80070021
To resolve this problem, unlock the specified section, or do not use it at that level. For more information on configuration locking, see How to Use Locking in IIS 7.0 Configuration.

So I am wondering if anyone else has faced this particular issue,
or, if anyone can give me any appreciated advice here.

Thanks for your time and advice. If you need more clues, just ask.

Comment: If you use IIS instead of IIS Express during development, you need to enable IIS in Windows. It is very likely that your windows feature configuration was changed or reset. If you hit start and type Windows features make sure that IIS IS checked

Comment: HI ALuan, yes, "web management tools" and "world wide web services"that is one the things i tried, but it has been set that way many backups ago. thanks.

Comment: Try to disable it and then re-enable it. sounds like something is corrupt. There's also a Powershell command for this although I don't recall it. Anyway you can try a few things starting with scaffolding a new project and seeing if it runs, if it doesn't you can try to prepare visual studio and if that doesn't work you can try to repair windows

Comment: thanks again, i have tried repair and reinstall of VS, same thing. As far as scaffolding, from what i know, it has to do with database stuff.  And even though i had that entity framework context issue, i cant address that now because i have to have my project load where i can login and get to the page where that entity framework context issue happens. but, as you can see, i   WAS getting my login page, but now, i cannot get through the browser connection.

Comment: I follow you. Something is very corrupt in your environment. There are various things that you could try but you could just reinstall or reset windows yourself. That's drastic but I don't know how much time you have to spend on this

Comment: I do agree with you that it looks like a corruption issue of the project, so, i think i will start down that rabbit hole at this point thanks to your corruption suggestion. 
  Here is something else i have tried, i copied this project from my new laptop to my old laptop and i got the same errors. So, i dont think IIS is the problem. other projects work on my old laptop.

Comment: Okay. If it fails on a different system, just try to recreate the project buy scaffolding a new one via Visual Studio. See what the differences are between that project file and what you currently have. I assume you're using some kind of Version Control oh, so you should be able to find a point in time where the code did work. Also, you may have bad IDE configuration in your.Vs folder

Comment: it just so happens that i got so new disk drives with more storage, and i put my new laptop in to install the drives and to reinstall a fresh copy of windows. it should be ready tommorrow, sunday. but if the project is corrupt, chances are that it will still have the issue on my new laptop. But, you know how it is, i will be busy for the next couple of days reinstalling all my programs on my new disk drive. BUT i have most of the day to work on this on my old laptop.

Comment: I do. But it's easy to create new projects in vs. If it fails on a completely different machine in the same way then you have to start somewhere. Hell try a different IDE. You're not going to be able to provide enough information here to cover all the possible variables on your system

Comment: I will look at the scaffolding and the IDE right now. thanks again !! Probably may not get back to this for the next couple of days after i reload all my programs on my new laptop disk drives.

Comment: Checkout jet brain's Rider. It will provide a valuable point of comparison and there's a 30-day trial

Comment: Well I uninstalled and reinstalled the VS IDE, twice, same issue. your right, it will be hard to post all of the variables of this problem. And yes,i had to start somewhere and this post was one of the places.

Comment: I'm not trying to give you a hard time. But, just as with a bug, you can rule things out step by step. So for example if you try the jetbrains IDE and it fails then you know the problem isn't related to visual studio. Anyway, you know that already.

Comment: Rider? ok, i will look at that. But it has to work in visual studio somehow, even if i have to recreate the project and just copy the proper files and folders from the old project to the new one. thats comming next. Cause if somethng is currupted, if might not be fixable. thanks again.

Comment: No hard time my friend. I made this forum post for suggestions that i may not have thought of.

Comment: Good luck. There's also a visual studio preview that you can install and it's a side-by-side installation so that's another point of comparison. I'm sure you've already done this, but make sure you delete all of your build artifacts and IDE configuration in the project folder. This includes hidden folders

Comment: VS Preview, hmmm, will follow the rest of your suggestions and will post back the results. i dont think i can do them all today, but i will start with the basics of creating a new project and copying stuff from the old to the new. wil keep you posted. thanks again for your quick response and great ideas!!!

Comment: Is your problem solved? your problem should be caused by the wrong configuration of the web.config file, you can try to reinstall vs and iis to restore the configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

The seems to happen after installing KB4568831.

https://superuser.com/questions/1575295/windows-updates-kb4568831-kb4562899-break-all-net-applications-hosted-in-iis

I could get rid of the `500.19` errors by manually re-installing some optional windows features that the update apparently removes (see below), but after I got auth-related errors instead. In the end I rolled back KB4568831 to resolve the issue for the time being. Hopefully this gets fixed soon.

[image]